# Working out the output of strsplit in R

Tags: regex, r, string, strsplit

I have the following string expression, to which I apply strsplit:

```
x="Hello I am using stack overflow to ask this question."
y=strsplit(x,"a")
```

The above function splits x when ever there is an 'a'. From my understanding, the returned vector should be a list, and so say I wanted to get the second fragment of x, I should be using:

```
y[[2]]
```

However, this gives me an error:

```
Error in y[[2]] : subscript out of bounds
```

I am not sure how to resolve this. All I want is to access the broken fragments of the string.

Answer (score 10):

The `strsplit` does return a list.  But, the `list` is only a single element list.

```
length(strsplit(x,'a'))
#[1] 1
```

To access, the 2nd `string` of a single element list,

```
strsplit(x,"a")[[1]][2]
#[1] "m using st"
```

Suppose, if you have a vector of elements

```
 a1 <- rep(x,3)
```

The `strsplit` returns a list with number of elements equal to the length of `a1`

```
 lst <- strsplit(a1,'a')
```

To get the `2nd` split string from the `lst`

```
 sapply(lst,`[`,2)
 #[1] "m using st" "m using st" "m using st"
```

Comment: Or you could just do `lst<-unlist(strsplit(a1,'a'))`  :-)